# calculate mean from list of rasters and and save it in a different name

Tags: r, raster

I have a list of rasters(.tif format) for multiple years. It is a 16 day NDVI from landsat, i want to make a monthly NDVI (average of two consecutive rasters) and save it in same or different directory as a monthly average

I have listed the raster rasters and make stack of it, later i used stackApply to calculate the mean, but it will produce empty raster. I have 23 images for single year, which i want to average it and make 12 months. This is how my raster files look like

```
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000001.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000017.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000033.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000049.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000065.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000081.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000097.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000113.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000129.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000145.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000161.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000177.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000193.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000209.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000225.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000241.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000257.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000273.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000289.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000305.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000321.tif" "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000337.tif"
 "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000353.tif
```

This code works but will produce more than twelve empty raster and i also want to save the raster brick as single subset monthly raster

```
library(raster)
lrast<-list.files("G:/LANDSAT-NDVI/testAverage")
layers<-paste("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000", seq(from=001, to=353,by=16))
stak<-stack(lrast)
raster<-stackApply(stak, layers, fun = mean)
```

I want to make a monthly average from landsatNDVISC05SLC2000001.tif and landsatNDVISC05SLC2000017.tif as landsatNDVISC05SLC2000M1.tif. Similarly, 33,49 and since i only have 23 raster, i want to retain landsatNDVISC05SLC2000353.tif as landsatNDVISC05SLC2000M12.tif

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure how stackapply works but something like this should do the stuff needed.

```
library(raster)
files <- list.files(path = "...", full.names = T, pattern = ".tif")

stk <- stack()

for (i in files){
  print(i)
  as <- raster(files[i])
  stk <- addLayer(stk, as)
}

jday <-c("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000017.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000033.tif",
"landsatNDVISC05SLC2000049.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000065.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000081.tif",
"landsatNDVISC05SLC2000097.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000113.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000129.tif",
"landsatNDVISC05SLC2000145.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000161.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000177.tif",
"landsatNDVISC05SLC2000193.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000209.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000225.tif",
"landsatNDVISC05SLC2000241.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000257.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000273.tif",
"landsatNDVISC05SLC2000289.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000305.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000321.tif",
"landsatNDVISC05SLC2000337.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000353.tif")

jday <- as.numeric(substr(jday, 24, 25)) #substract the julien days (which I think these number represent before .tif; or you can substract the names from the 'files' vector)

dates <- as.Date(jday, origin=as.Date("2000-01-01")) # create a Date vector

stk <- setZ(stk, dates) # assign the date vector to the raster stack

raster <- zApply(stk, by = format(dates,"%Y-%m"), fun = mean, na.rm = T) # create the monthly stack
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei Nita, when i run the setZ function it gives "Error in setZ(stak, dates) : 
  length(z) == nlayers(x) is not TRUE", is it because when i printed the dates, it starts with 2000-01-02 even if the origin is 2000-01-01? the stacked layer and dates are of similar length (23 layers in my case).

Comment: length(z) == nlayers(x)  is it TRUE? The fact that the date starts with 2000-01-02 shouldn't be a problem as long as it does have the same length as the number of layers in the stack.

Comment: For some reason, these single band tiff image is recognized as two band tiff, so when i query the nlayers, it showed 46 layers, but in real its only 23 layers. Still could not figure out the problem. Thanks Andrei for your effort

Comment: I updated the answer. It looks like you read the same raster twice. However, it's hard to give an answer without looking at the data :)